# AIR LocalConnection in IE 10 Windows 8 not working

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer, localconnection

Microsoft recently done this update for flash in IE10
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2758994

after which our product, that was working fine across all browser stopped working totally in IE10.
We have a flash WebUI which connects to Desktop AIR App using LocalConnection class.
There are now exceptions and no information on this in web.
And product continues to work fine in all other browsers so that's not the code's issue.
The only similar issue that i found is here - http://forums.adobe.com/message/5103110

Has anyone else encountered something like this? or any ideas on how it can be solved?
I would very appreciate any advice